# Java POJO Modeling - List of objects vs multiple fields for each object

Tags: java, modeling, pojo, software-design

I'm trying to create a POJO model class. Model `Person` has multiple Addresses like `physicalAddress` and `mailingAddress`. Would it make sense to have a list of addresses in the POJO and multiple variables of type `Address`?

###### Address

```
public class Address {
    private String type; // this will be added if address will be used as list in Person Class
    private String line1;
    private String line2;
    private String line3;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

#### Option 1

```
public class Person {
    private Address physicalAddress;
    private Address mailingAddress;
}
```

#### Option 2

```
public class Person {
    private List<Address> addresses; // in this case address object will have a variable called type
}
```

Should I go with option 1 or option 2? I kind of think I should go with option 1 since getting and setting would be easy.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think this depends heavily on your requirements and the nature of your application.  Unless you have something that you can actually do with a list of 50 addresses, why do you want that?

Comment: I agree. max 4 address types. I think I'll go with option 1. Thanks for the response!

Comment: If you plan to track the history of _all_ addresses of a person, it makes sense to have a list of addresses, otherwise it's sufficient to maintain one address per type.   Also, you might want to have some boolean flag `mailingAddressSameAsPhysical` etc.

Comment: How will you differentiate between any two indexes in the array?

Comment: I would suggest option 1 if you know number of addresses and its not going to increase otherwise go with option 2 if number of addresses is not known and may increase in future.

Comment: [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) may be a better fit for this question.  It may get closed as opinion-based here.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen each address will have a type.

Comment: thank you all for responding. I ended up going with Option 1. appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I think option one sounds a little easier to me. If you're going to be sending it in a http request in Json format, it's usually nice if it's more flat.

Having it in a list may make it harder to parse back from Json.

But it might be ok anyway